# Angular UI-Grid Tree View - Change the Column Header for Child Tree Levels

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm looking into creating a single-page application that shows some tabular data. The business sponsors for this project would like for this data to be displayed as a tree-grid, where each "parent level" row lists a series of data points, and its "child level" row will list specific data points, relative to its parent.

However, those "child level" rows need to have different headers than its parent, and I'm not sure how to change them; or if it's even possible! The example shown on the official [UI Grid Tree View](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView) page shows each of the child rows to having the same header as its parent, but doesn't demonstrate the option to change the header. Is that possible? And if so, how do you do it?

Below is a (very crude) example of what I'm looking for:

[image: Tree Grid Example]

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! I suppose I should have been more thorough in my searching. Thank you, @KScandrett