# AngularJS UI-Grid Tree View: How can child rows have different column names than parent rows?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angular-ui-grid, angular-tree-component

I am trying to have different columns and column names for child rows than the parents rows in TreeView in UI-Grid
[image]

There is already a question asked, but the link provided in the comment section has expired.
[Angular UI-Grid Tree View - Change the Column Header for Child Tree Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540546/angular-ui-grid-tree-view-change-the-column-header-for-child-tree-levels)

Comment: Can you please add some snippets with plunker with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. We can use expandable grid to achieve this feature.

Link to [UI-Grid Expandable Grid Documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20216%20Expandable%20grid)